# Package additional in-tree modules

Tags: linux, kernel, package-management, rpm, kernel-modules

Targeting an up to date Fedora whose kernel unfortunately lacks a module:
Is it possible to package the module (using kmod or whatever existing
infrastructure), so that

- the module package has the distro’s kernel as a dependency (it’ll go into a
  local dnf repo for easy install);
- once installed, the module can be `modprobe(8)`ed (it’s not needed
  in the initramfs);
- only the kernel source is required, no additional packaging of the module
  source;
- in order to build the package, only the module needs to be compiled, not the
  entire kernel (puny hardware; of course one initial kernel build would be
  reasonable);
- given an SRPM, `rpmbuild(8)` will be enough to create the package (no
  manual `make modules` etc. required)?

Note that I’m not interested in building out-of-tree modules which is
documented well enough already. Since I only need that single module I would
prefer to avoid setting up a cross compilation environment. I’m familiar with
OpenWRT’s package management which allows for packaging and distributing
individual modules, so I assume it’s possible somehow. How would one accomplish
it with RPM?